# Rotating Coordinate System

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

How to visualize  rotating frame of reference ?

Comment: Just make up a real life example in your head. Imagine this: You're sitting on a big disc, which is not spinning and observe a ball 3m away from you. You can describe its position with a constant vector $\vec{r}$. Now imagine that the disc begins to spin with a constant angular velocity $\omega$. What would you see?

Comment: When disc is moving will it affect the motion of the ball ? i.e. is there any physical contact  of the moving ball  with the surface of the spinning disc for example the disc is rotating and the ball in moving  toward the negative x direction  on the plane of the disc . So will it 
 continue to move  in  the same direction ( negative x direction) with the rotating disc ?  or its direction will change. I am asking this one because the position vector r of the particle will be equal whether the disc is rotating or not.

Comment: The disc does not have any contact with the ball. But you already seem understand the relative motion of yourself and the ball. @ja72's answer contains the equations of such coordinate transformations, so it should be possible to extract an understanding from that by inserting a nice little example and see that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Say point *C* is the origin of the moving frame. Point *P* is the location of the particle. The kinematics are such that the coordinate of *P* in the fixed frame are $\boldsymbol{r}_P$, but in the moving frame $\boldsymbol{p}$. The origin of the moving frame is $\boldsymbol{r}_C$ and so we have:

$$\boldsymbol{r}_P = \boldsymbol{r}_C + \boldsymbol{p} $$

Take the derivative of the above to derive the velocity of *P*.

$$ \frac{{\rm d} \boldsymbol{r}_P}{{\rm d}t} = \frac{{\rm d} \boldsymbol{r}_C}{{\rm d}t} + \frac{{\rm d} \boldsymbol{p}}{{\rm d}t}$$

$$ \boldsymbol{v}_P = \boldsymbol{v}_C + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{p}$$

Regardless of the motion of the moving frame (and Point *C*) the result is a vector field where the magnitude of the velocity depends on the perpendicular distance to a rotation axis, and the direction is always in the "hoop" orientation about this axis.

The instantaneous axis of rotation goes through a point *A*, whose location depends on the velocity of the moving frame

$$\boxed{ \boldsymbol{r}_A = \boldsymbol{r}_C + \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{v}_C}{\| \boldsymbol{\omega} \|^2} }$$

If $\boldsymbol{v}_C=0$ then $\boldsymbol{r}_A = \boldsymbol{r}_C$.

- *Proof*:

  The instantaneous axis of rotation has the property that the linear velocity at *A* is zero  $\boldsymbol{v}_C + \boldsymbol{\omega}\times ( \boldsymbol{r}_A - \boldsymbol{r}_C ) =0$ or $\boldsymbol{v}_C = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times ( \boldsymbol{r}_C - \boldsymbol{r}_A )$.

  Take $\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{v}_C$ and expanded it using the vector triple product identity

  $$\require{cancel} \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{v}_C = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \left(\boldsymbol{\omega}\times ( \boldsymbol{r}_C - \boldsymbol{r}_A )\right) = \boldsymbol{\omega} \left(\cancel{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot (\boldsymbol{r}_C-\boldsymbol{r}_A)} \right) - (\boldsymbol{r}_C-\boldsymbol{r}_A)\,( \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega}) $$

  $$ \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{v}_C }{ \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \|^2 } = \boldsymbol{r}_A - \boldsymbol{r}_C $$

  Use the fact that the vector from point *A* to point *C* is perpendicular to the rotation vector.